# has_many :through, :source, :source_type returning empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, has-many-through, has-many, has-many-polymorphs

I got some `Manager` and `SoccerTeam` model. A manager "owns" many soccer teams; also a manager can comment on soccer teams and can comment on other managers too:

**manager.rb**

```
# Soccer teams the manager owns
has_many :soccer_teams, :dependent => :restrict
# Comments the manager has made on soccer teams or other managers
has_many :reviews, :class_name => "Comment", :foreign_key => :author_id, :dependent => :destroy
# Comments the manager has received by other managers
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
# Soccer teams that have received a comment by the manager
has_many :observed_teams, :through => :comments, :source => :commentable, :source_type => "SoccerTeam"
```

**soccer_team.rb**

```
# The manager that owns the team
belongs_to :manager
# Comments received by managers
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
# Managers that have reviewed the team
has_many :observers, :through => :comments, :source => :author, :class_name => "Manager"
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :author, :class_name => Manager
```

Now, if I have a Manager commenting on a SoccerTeam I expect to find:

- A `Comment` object in `manager.reviews` and in `soccer_team.comments`
- A `SoccerTeam` object in `manager.observed_teams`
- A `Manager` object in `soccer_team.observers`

While everything works well for the first and the third point, when I call `manager.observed_teams` I always obtain an empty array. To actually obtain the list of soccer teams a manager has commented on I need to use:

```
manager.reviews.collect{ |review| Kernel.const_get(review.commentable_type).find(review.commentable_id) if review.commentable_type == "SoccerTeam" }
```

Which is ugly. I expect the simple `manager.observed_teams` to work… why it doesn't?

**Edit**

I went a step further in understanding why it does not work. In fact, the genrated SQL is:

```
SELECT "soccer_teams".* FROM "soccer_teams" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "soccer_teams".id = "soccer_teams".commentable_id AND "comments".commentable_type = 'SoccerTeam' WHERE (("comments".commentable_id = 1) AND ("comments".commentable_type = 'Manager'))
```

While I want it to be:

```
SELECT "soccer_teams".* FROM "soccer_teams" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "soccer_teams".id = "comments".commentable_id AND "comments".commentable_type = 'SoccerTeam' WHERE ("comments".author_id = 1)
```

So the question is simple: how to obtain that query? (An heuristic attempt with `:foreign_key` ans `:as`, as expected, hasn't solved the problem!).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you've simply used the wrong association for `observed_teams`. Instead of

```
has_many :observed_teams, :through => :comments, 
  :source => :commentable, :source_type => "SoccerTeam"
```

Try this:

```
has_many :observed_teams, :through => :reviews,
 :source => :commentable, :source_type => "SoccerTeam"
```

Also in,

```
has_many :reviews, :class_name => :comment, 
  :foreign_key => :author_id, :dependent => :destroy
```

`:comment` should be `'Comment'`

and in

```
has_many :comments, :as => commentable, :dependent => :destroy
```

`commmentable` should be `:commmentable`

Comment: The last two were typos… but you definitely get the point on the association! Thanks.